# GridView with Jquery data table implementation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Recently I was trying to use the features of "https://datatables.net" in one GridView render. It wasn't possible because the render always gives a table without the correct formatting (without thead). Is there a way to transform the render into the correct format?

Correct format:

```html
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code formats one table to the correct format and then runs the `.DataTable();` on the corrected formatted table.

To use this replace the ID of your table in '#gdVscQuote'

If the page you are working on has more than one table this will not work, is not tested.

```js
 $(document).ready( function () {
        //replace tr
        $($('#gdVscQuote')[0].childNodes[1].childNodes[0]).wrap('<thead/>').contents().unwrap();
        //replace all td with th inside thead
        $('thead td').wrap('<th/>').contents().unwrap();
        //get thead
        var thead = $("thead").get(0);
        //remove saved thead to replace above tbody thead
        $("thead").remove();
        //add thead correctly
        $('#gdVscQuote')[0].prepend(thead);
        // replace tds for tr
        $($('thead')[0].childNodes).wrapAll("<tr/>")
        //add jQuery table functionality
        $('#gdVscQuote').DataTable();
});
```